# No such module only when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using xcode 7.3.1 at the moment. I have a workspace set up with an iOS app project and two framework projects.

1. MyiOSApp (imports 2 and 3)
2. AppSharedFramework (imports 3)
3. CompanySharedFramework (This we will split into its own thing one day)

I can build each of these projects fine when running on the simulator, I can also build then all for Profiling (which uses the release build). But as soon as I try archive either 1 or 2 the build fails with "No such module 'CompanySharedFramework'"

I've been struggling to get this to archive for quite some time, what could cause this issue during archive, but not during run/profile builds.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you have different build settings for debug and release which is causing this.  Examine them carefully.

Comment: Would this not also appear when doing "Build for profile" and profile does a release build?

Comment: By default, yes, profiling uses the release build configuration.

Comment: I am having same issue, Any resolve?

Answer (score 7):

In my main project, a long time ago, I created a new "configuration schema" called "AppStore" that was duplicated from Xcode's default "Release" configuration. I added an entire Xcode project (a framework project) to my project. I was able to `@import MyFramework;` when "Running" because both projects had "Debug" as the schema for "Running" the app. When I went to Archive it, my main project was setup to use "AppStore" config (as opposed to the default of "Release") and my sub project did not have an "AppStore" config. Once I added "AppStore" to the sub project based on "Release", when I went to archive it worked great, built fully, because both projects now had the AppStore schema and the main project is the one saying to use that config when archiving, so when I just created it in the sub project things started working like you'd expect.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this! I was struggling for hours until I found you solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pod file in your project, please run `pod install` command even if you already run the command.
Good lucky!

Answer (score 0):

@John Erck and @Victor Poroshenko inspired me.

Just one rule, if main project has a config named "AppStore", sub-projects in the same workspace which used by your main project also need a config named "AppStore".

Two situation in my case:

1. For the sub project you imported into the workspace manually, add the "AppStore" for it manually.
2. For pod files, just run `pod install`, it will generate the missing `Pods-PROJECT_NAME.appstore.xcconfig` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting

> `Pods folder`, `xcworkspace`, `Podfile.Lock`

and reinstalling Pods

> `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

When receiving "Module not found" error (while using `@import`) make sure module target version is not higher than main (application) target